# Problema com código enviado por POST

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e preciso armazenar um código a um certo item e este código que passo por POST, não está sendo salvo no banco, o mesmo quando é passado, é gravado o item, porém na coluna deste código fica zerado.
Segue códigos:

O FORM QUE ENVIA:

```
<div id="gravaeditapauta">
    <form action="gravarpauta.php" method="POST">

   <?php
    include ("conectarbanco.php");

    $passacodigoreuniao=$_GET["addcodpauta"]; 
    $selecionalinha= mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT Data FROM reuniao where CodReuniao=$passacodigoreuniao");
    $campo= mysqli_fetch_array($selecionalinha);

    ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="CodReuniao" value="<?=$campo["CodReuniao"]?>">
    <label for="data">Data da Reunião:</label>&nbsp &nbsp<input type="text" name="data" size="20" maxlength="10" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$campo["Data"]?>">
    <br></br>

    <label for="DescItem">Inserir Item de Pauta:</label>&nbsp &nbsp<input type="text" name="DescItem" size="50" maxlength="50">

    <br></br>

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Gravar Item de Pauta">

</form> 
</div>
```

O bloco de comando para inserção no banco:

```
<?php

include ("conectarbanco.php");

$passacodigoreuniao=$_POST["CodReuniao"];
$data=$_POST["data"];
$DescItem=$_POST["DescItem"];

mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO itenspauta(DescItem,CodReuniao) values ('$DescItem','$passacodigoreuniao')") or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

?>
```

Comment: Procure se informar sobre quão inseguro é o uso do mysqli_query com variáveis $dentro do comando SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
Altere a seguinte linha:

$selecionalinha= mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT Data FROM reuniao where CodReuniao=$passacodigoreuniao");

Para isto:
$selecionalinha= mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT Data,CodReuniao FROM reuniao where CodReuniao=$passacodigoreuniao");

Vc esqueceu de incluir o **CodReuniao**

Abçs.

Comment: Mano, muito obrigado, era isso mesmo. Seu lugar no céu já está garantido aaaaaah muito grato mesmo 